# Python3: read column-by-column from text file, multiply columns with number and store in another file.

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

This is probably very basic question but I am unable to find any solution (or I am poor at finding one)- tried for 1 entire day. 
I have a text file. I want to read in column-by-column. The file looks something like this (e.g.):

---

```
#no&glon&glat&fwhm1&fwhm2&comments\\
1&90&30&-&3&some\\
2&89&31&4&7&commnts\\
3&87&32&6&9&\\
4&88&33&1&4&\\
5&84&23&-&-&\\
```

---

Missing values are represented with "-". Each line ends with "\\". I need this because ultimately i export the entire table to Latex.

Program goes like this:

```
`data = np.genfromtxt('test.txt',comments='#',delimiter = '&', missing_values = '-', usecols = (0,1,2,3,4))
no = d[:,0]
glon = d[:,1]
glat = d[:,2]
fwhm1 = d[:,3]
fwhm2 = d[:,4]  
value1 = fwhm1 * 1.29
value2 = fwhm2 * 0.8 `
```

Now, I want to store them again (with value1 and value2) column-by-column in another file (text or csv) with '&' as delimiter. How do it do it?

I tried the following but failed in Python3

```
F = open('test.txt','w') 
for i in range(0,len(no)): 
        print >> F, '{:20f}{:20f}{:20f}'.format(no[i],value1[i],value2[i])
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you want, `print ('{:20f}{:20f}{:20f}'.format(no[i],value1[i],value2[i]), file=F)`

Comment: Wow! Is that all? Because print >> is outdated in Python 3 ? @BillBell

Comment: That's the main thing anyway. You might need to consider providing for decimal places since you multiplied by 1.29 and 0.8. Possibly `'{:20.3f}'` for right-justified with 3 d.p.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BillBell. That solved the issue! :) Ah okay! I will take care of that decimal place as per your suggestion.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Hi @BillBell, do you know what can i do to incorporate string format along with the float at the same time? e.g. if i have a data like, 1.2e20 or 1.2E+20

Comment: That actually appears to be a large floating point number, in which case you could format it with `'{:>20.3g}'.format(a)` (or with the 'e' or 'E' formats, see 'Format Specification Mini-Language' in the help file). If it really is a string then you can use `'{:>20}'.format(a)`.